# Creating Functions that take into account Deposit and Withdrawl

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Program at the moment gives out a balance for a class Bank Account, which in the scenario is chosen to be 1000.
However, I want my program to take into account this scenario.

```
acc1=BankAccount(1000.0)
acc1.deposit(123.5)
acc1.withdraw(200.0)
```

With this scenario, it should output

```
Deposit requested 123.5
balance=1123.5
Withdrawal requested 200.0
balance=923.5
```

I just want some help with creating method definitions for deposit and withdrawal, because the balance in between would just be printing the bank account balance plus or minus the deposit or withdrawal functions respectively.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.balance = b
    def display(self):
        print("Balance : "+ str(self.balance))

acc1 = BankAccount(1000.0)
acc1.display()
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far. The methods literally just need to add or subtract from the balance.

Comment: Well, I am still stumped. I am thinking it would be the same as the self.balance.

Comment: `self.balance -= amount` and `self.balance += amount`?

Comment: def __init__ (self,withdraw) and the same for deposit.

Comment: Are you guys doing the same homework? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469510/instantiating-object-and-using-class-definition-init

Comment: Oh wow, what a coincidence! I am taking a summer course and have no idea of my classmates. I'll try to get in contact with him and see if we can help each other out

Comment: StackOverflow at it's finest :-)

Comment: Yeah, I am new to this site but I had one more question that I forgot to add on here, I put it in the replies of the answer because they said I am only allowed to ask one question every 90 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example you could expand off of:

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.balance = b

    def display(self):
        print("Balance : "+ str(self.balance))

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
```

In practice:

```
ba = BankAccount(1000)

ba.deposit(100)

print(ba.balance)

> 1100
```

Adding conditions:

```
def withdraw(self, amount):
    if amount <= self.balance:
        self.balance -= amount
    else:
        print("You can't withdraw more than your balance.")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. One more question I have is putting an error if the withdrawal is more than the balance. I tried putting an if statement of if withdraw < 0: print that there is not enough money in the account, but this gave me an error of the < sign not being supported.

Comment: @WilgensMetelus I updated the post with an example concerning conditional statements :D